# Migrate theme settings between multisite installations

Tags: 7, migrations

I have set up a second site on a multisite development instance of Drupal 7. We're using a subtheme based on Adaptive Themes. Being that plans call for about a dozen sibling sites, I would like to copy this over theme settings from the first site to each subsequent sibling sites.

What tools would be recommended for this arena?

Someone suggested using Features. However, of the options I don't see a way to package up theme settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far what I've been able to figure out, the answer is -- it depends. It depends on what you're moving between installations.

Features module has worked best for me to move *configuration* settings or for modules (and their dependents). Sometimes, you'll have to include the strong arm values inside the Feature export.

For user content, it's best to use Migrate (or Backup and Migrate).